# Loop through columns combining two data frames in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse

I have the 2 following separate data frames:

| itens | sp1 | sp2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| item1 | 20 | 10 |
| item2 | 30 | 15 |
| item3 | 30 | 15 |
| item4 | 30 | 15 |

and

| itens | sp5 | sp6 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| item7 | 20 | 10 |
| item8 | 30 | 15 |
| item9 | 30 | 15 |

How could I create, in R, a for function that produce the following result?

| sps | sum | N |
| --- | --- | --- |
| sp1 | 110 | 4 |
| sp2 | 55 | 4 |
| sp5 | 80 | 3 |
| sp6 | 40 | 3 |

Where each N and sum columns , in this new data frame, are number and sum of itens of each species (sps).

Thank you

Comment: Please present data with `dput` so that others can easily copy-paste it.

Comment: Does it have to be a for loop (if so: why is there a tidyverse tag?) And it would be easier to help you if your data was in code form...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df1 <- structure(list(itens = c("item1", "item2", "item3", "item4"), 
                      sp1 = c(20L, 30L, 30L, 30L), 
                      sp2 = c(10L, 15L, 15L, 15L)), 
                 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))

df2 <- structure(list(itens = c("item7", "item8", "item9"),
                      sp5 = c(20L,  30L, 30L), 
                      sp6 = c(10L, 15L, 15L)), 
                 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,  -3L))
```

Solution not using a loop but `tidyr::pivot_longer` `and dplyr::full_join`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df1 %>% 
  pivot_longer(-itens) %>% 
  full_join(df2 %>%  pivot_longer(-itens)) %>% 
  group_by(sps = name) %>% 
  summarise(N = n(),
            sum = sum(value))
```

Returns:

```
  sps      N   sum
  <chr> <int> <int>
1 sp1       4   110
2 sp2       4    55
3 sp5       3    80
4 sp6       3    40
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution, based on and `dplyr::bind_rows` and `tidyr::pivot_longer`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df1 <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
             itens = c("item1", "item2", "item3", "item4"),
               sp1 = c(20L, 30L, 30L, 30L),
               sp2 = c(10L, 15L, 15L, 15L)
       )
  
df2 <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
             itens = c("item7", "item8", "item9"),
               sp5 = c(20L, 30L, 30L),
               sp6 = c(10L, 15L, 15L)
       )

df1 %>% 
  bind_rows(df2) %>% 
  pivot_longer(-itens, names_to = "sps") %>% 
  group_by(sps) %>% 
  summarise(sum = sum(value,na.rm = T), N = sum(!is.na(value)))

#> # A tibble: 4 × 3
#>   sps     sum     N
#>   <chr> <int> <int>
#> 1 sp1     110     4
#> 2 sp2      55     4
#> 3 sp5      80     3
#> 4 sp6      40     3
```